# what factor do trinomial have in common?

Tags: polynomials

> What factor do the following trinomials have in common?
>
> $$4x^2+13x+3\, \text{ and }\, 8x^2+22x-6$$

My try:

$$4x^2 + 13x +3 = (4x+1)(x+3)$$

$$8x^2 + 22x - 6 = 2(4x-1)(x+3)$$

The trinomials have no common factor.

Answer (score 6):

Both trinomials have a factor of $(x+3)$.

$$4x^2 + 13x +3 = (4x+1)\color{blue}{ (x+3)}$$

$$8x^2 + 22x - 6 = 2(4x-1)\color{blue}{ (x+3)}$$